# Getting Amazon Spronsored Brands Campaigns via API

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I have a client who is using Sponsored Brands (sb) campaigns and some of the campaigns have a type of

```
Sponsored Brands
Manual targeting - Video
```

For some reason the API doesn't return this type of campaigns when fetching via v3

```
GET /sb/campaigns
```

or v2

```
/v2/hsa/campaigns
```

It only returns the non-video campaigns.

Has anybody worked with this type of campaigns via the API?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested your requests on this page: https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/sponsored-brands/3-0/openapi

Comment: ... or you can download the specification and import it into Postman: https://d3a0d0y2hgofx6.cloudfront.net/openapi/en-us/sponsored-brands/3-0/openapi.yaml and then test your requests and play around with the filter settings

Comment: @tector Yes, I tried using the requests in https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/sponsored-brands/3-0/openapi. Still, some campaigns were not being returned but I could see them in the Vendor Central UI.